# how can i manually set GrailsUtil.environment variable in Bootstrap.groovy

Tags: grails

At the time bootstrap.groovy is running GrailsUtil.environment is automatically switch to development.

Can any one explain,How can i manually change that variable before bootstrap starts..??

Where it is setting as default to development in grails framework..??

Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

Your grails environment is specified on the command line when you type `run-app`, for example.  I don't believe you can switch the environment setting within Bootstrap.groovy--or any file--at runtime.  Instead, you can change it by how you execute the grails commands:

`-Dgrails.env=production run-app`-- you can create your own environments to run, just change the value for `-Dgrails.env` to your custom environment.

Some of the grails tasks will run in a given environment by default; you don't need to set it explicitly.

1. `run-app` -- defaults to run in the `development` environment
2. `test-app` -- defaults to `test` environment
3. `war` -- defaults to `production` environment

More info here:  http://www.grails.org/Environments

Comment: from grails documentations, to run required environment {env run-app} Example : {test run-app} not {test-app}